# DNS: how to wild match *.dev to localhost and others default

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

My raw DNS setting in `/etc/resolv.conf` is `8.8.8.8` , and now I set it to `127.0.0.1`

I want to match *.dev to localhost, and others goes to `8.8.8.8`, how to do this?

Comment: Why BIND and not something such as dnsmasq?

Comment: thanks, resolved. dnsmasq  `address=/dev/127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this from the bare UNIX resolver. You need to set up a local DNS cache to do the routing. There are several trivial to configure; it will take you about 10 minutes with dnscache (see http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/dnscache.html "scans the servers directory") or dnsmasq (http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/setup.html "Using special servers"). You don't need one cache per client, you can set up one such forwarding cache for the whole network, and then route other clients through it.